# how to get html class values using regular expression in ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I have this below string from which I want to extract class values "ruby", "html", "java". My objective here is understanding / learning regular expressions that I have always dreaded :-).

```
<div class="ruby" name="ruby_doc">
<div class="html" name="html_doc">
<div class="java" name="java_doc">
```

This is what I have so far

```
str = <<END
<div class="ruby" name="ruby_doc">
<div class="html" name="html_doc">
<div class="java" name="java_doc">
END

str.scan(/"[^"]+/) #=> returns
["\"ruby", "\" name=", "\"ruby_doc", "\">\n<div class=", "\"html",...]

str.scan(/class="[^"]+/) #=> ["class=\"ruby", "class=\"html", "class=\"java"]

str.scan(/"(\w)+?"/) #=> [["ruby"], ["ruby_doc"], ["html"], ["html_doc"], ...]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
str.scan(/\b(?<=class=\")[^"]+(?=\")/)
# => ["ruby", "html", "java"]
```

Answer (score 3):

Use  <kbd>[**`Nokogiri`**](http://nokogiri.org/)</kbd>  for this :

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML::Document.parse <<-_html_
<div class="ruby" name="ruby_doc">
<div class="html" name="html_doc">
<div class="java" name="java_doc">
_html_

# to get values of class attribute
doc.xpath('//div/@class').map(&:to_s)
# => ["ruby", "html", "java"]
# to get values of name attribute
doc.xpath('//div/@name').map(&:to_s)
# => ["ruby_doc", "html_doc", "java_doc"]
```

Comment: Since this is part of my regular expression learning, I am looking to achieve it with regex.

Comment: @Bala For html always use html parser,don't use RegEx.. See this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 2):

Parsing HTML with regex is not recommended. If you had to write a somewhat ok regex,  then you could try with

```
 str.scan /<div\s+class=\s*"([^"]+)/
 #=> [["ruby"], ["html"], ["java"]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You really should use Nokogiri as per @Arup's answer. But, if you insist...

```
str.scan(/(?:class\=\")(\w+)(?:\")/).flatten
```

#### Live test in Ruby console

```
2.0.0p247 :001 > str = <<END
2.0.0p247 :002"> <div class="ruby" name="ruby_doc">
2.0.0p247 :003"> <div class="html" name="html_doc">
2.0.0p247 :004"> <div class="java" name="java_doc">
2.0.0p247 :005"> END
 => "<div class=\"ruby\" name=\"ruby_doc\">\n<div class=\"html\" name=\"html_doc\">\n<div class=\"java\" name=\"java_doc\">\n" 
2.0.0p247 :006 > str.scan(/(?:class\=\")(\w+)(?:\")/).flatten
 => ["ruby", "html", "java"]
```

Comment: Can I request you please explain what each regex group does?

Comment: The first group requires that `class="` be present, but not captured. The second group captures any sequence of word characters. The third group requires that `"` be present, but not captured.

Answer (score -3):

Howsabout:

```
str.scan /"(.*?)"/
#=> [["ruby"], ["ruby_doc"], ["html"], ["html_doc"], ["java"], ["java_doc"]]
```